# Procedure or function expects parameter, which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am calling a simple stored procedure written in SQL Server 2008 with parameter from c# but it display error 
***"Procedure or function 'AddYear' expects parameter '@mYear', which was not supplied."***

What's wrong with this code, i tried several things but didn't successed.

```
    SqlCommand AddEquip = new SqlCommand("AddYear", dbConn);
    SqlDataReader rdrEquip;

    SqlParameter mP = new SqlParameter("@mYear",SqlDbType.VarChar ) ;

    mP.Value = "1990";

    AddEquip.Parameters.Add(mP);


    rdrEquip = AddEquip.ExecuteReader();
```

-- Parameter Name & type are the same i use in the Procedure.

Answer (score 12):

Seems like you forgot to set the `SqlCommand` as stored-procedure:

```
SqlCommand AddEquip = new SqlCommand("AddYear", dbConn);
AddEquip.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the parameter to your SqlParameter e.g:

```
mP = new SqlParameter("@mYear", SqlDbType.VarChar, PARAMETER_HERE);
```

Comment: They are setting the value in the following line. Should work fine according to the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.value.aspx

Answer (score -1):

if your Storedprocedure is expecting a parament than you have to pass it sqlcommand object

```
 SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[0];
            param[0] = new SqlParameter("@mYear", "1990");
rdrEquip = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(Con, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "SPC_proc", param);
```

i am using sqlhelper class here.