# C# Stored procedure or function expects parameter which is not supplied

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am fairly new to C# and I'm trying to set up call to a stored procedure in my database which takes one parameter.

I get the error "Procedure or function 'SP_getName' expects parameter '@username', which was not supplied. "

My Stored procedure works ok when I supply it with the parameter and I run it via SQL management studio.

```
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[SP_getName]
    @username = 'bob101'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

However when I try and call it the error is with how I'm passing the parameter in, but I can't spot what the issue is.

```
           //create a sql command object to hold the results of the query
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

            //and a reader to process the results
            SqlDataReader reader;

            //Instantiate return string
            string returnValue = null;

            //execute the stored procedure to return the results
            cmd.CommandText = "SP_getName";

            //set up the parameters for the stored procedure
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "bob101";

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = this.Connection;

            // then call the reader to process the results
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Any help in spotting my error would be greatly appreciated!

I've also tried looking at these two posts, but I haven't had any luck:

[Stored procedure or function expects parameter which is not supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703653/stored-procedure-or-function-expects-parameter-which-is-not-supplied)

[Procedure or function expects parameter, which was not supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900301/procedure-or-function-expects-parameter-which-was-not-supplied)

Thanks!

Comment: BTW, you should not use SP_ as a prefix for your procedures. That is reserved for system procs. If MS releases a proc with the same name at some point yours will not run anymore. Honestly you should not use a prefix at all, they add nothing for clarity.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have stated:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

Therefore you are simply executing:

```
SP_getName
```

Which works because it is the first statement in the batch, so you can call the procedure without `EXECUTE`, but you aren't actually including the parameter. Change it to

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Or you can change your CommandText to:

```
EXECUTE SP_getName @username;
```

As a side note you should [Avoid using the prefix 'sp_' for your stored procedures](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

And a further side note would be to use `using` with IDisposable objects to ensure they are disposed of correctly:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
using (var cmd = new new SqlCommand("SP_getName", connection))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "bob101";
    connection.Open();
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // Do something 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant - thanks for the information, worked great! Will mark as answer when the time limit is up! :D

Comment: Thanks - will definitely rename my stored procedure and read up on `using`!

Comment: Thanks! was helpful

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, but it wasn't about parameter name of Command Type.
My problem was that when C# calls SP, for each parameter that has no value passes 'default' keyword (i found it in SQL Profiler):

```
... @IsStop=0,@StopEndDate=default,@Satellite=0, ...
```

in my case my parameter Type was DateTime :

```
@StopEndDate datetime
```

. I Solved my problem by seting default value to this parameter in Stored Procedure :

```
@StopEndDate datetime=null
```

Comment: (correctionin in first line of my answer) parameter name or Command Type

Answer (score 0):

Try remove `@`:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "bob101";
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I still get the error message: "Procedure or function 'SP_getName' expects parameter '@username', which was not supplied. "